# Diagonalize $f(A)= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} A $

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have to diagonalize the endomorphism $f\in \mathrm{End(M_2}(\mathbb{R}))$ defined by
$f(A)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
A
$

I know I can rewrite it, if $A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$, as $f(A)=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
3c-a & 3d-b
\end{pmatrix}
$,

but I don't know how to continue. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pick up a basis of $\mathrm M_2(\Bbb R)$, find out the action of $f$ on these, and write down the matrix of $f$, then do the diagonalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Choose a basis for $\mathrm M_2(\mathbb R)$, say $\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}\}$. Calculate $f(E_{ij})$ and write it in the basis. This will give you matrix for $f$ (it's $4\times 4$). Proceed to diagonalize it as usual.

It might help if you think of $\mathrm M_2(\mathbb R)\cong \mathbb R^4$. Then $f$ becomes $$f(a,b,c,d) = (a,b,3c-a,3d-b).$$

Comment: So then, I just have to diagonalize the following matrix, right? $
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: @Gibbs, correct.

Comment: This was easier than I thought! Thanks!!

Comment: @Gibbs, you are welcome. Don't let algebra structure of $\mathrm M_2$ confuse you - it's just $4$-dimensional vector space with canonical basis.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $\lambda$ an eigenvalue and $A\ne 0$ an associated eigenvector so

$$f(A)=\lambda A\iff \begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda &0\\ -1 & 3-\lambda\end{pmatrix}A=0$$

Since $A\ne0$ so $\begin{pmatrix}1-\lambda &0\\ -1 & 3-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ should not be invertible hence $\lambda\in\{1,3\}$. Now for every value of $\lambda$ solve the equation $f(A)=\lambda A$ for $A=\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ to find the associated eigenspace.